# How to turn a list into a paginated JSON response for REST?

Tags: python, json, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django REST Framework and I faced a problem.

I'm building a backend for a social app. The task is to return a paginated JSON response to client. In the docs I only found how to do that for model instances, but what I have is a list:

```
[368625, 507694, 687854, 765213, 778491, 1004752, 1024781, 1303354, 1311339, 1407238, 1506842, 1530012, 1797981, 2113318, 2179297, 2312363, 2361973, 2610241, 3005224, 3252169, 3291575, 3333882, 3486264, 3860625, 3964299, 3968863, 4299124, 4907284, 4941503, 5120504, 5210060, 5292840, 5460981, 5622576, 5746708, 5757967, 5968243, 6025451, 6040799, 6267952, 6282564, 6603517, 7271663, 7288106, 7486229, 7600623, 7981711, 8106982, 8460028, 10471602]
```

Is there some nice way to do it? Do I have to serialize it in some special way?

What client is waiting for is:

```
{"users": [{"id": "368625"}, {"id": "507694"}, ...]}
```

The question is: How to paginate such response?

Any input is highly appreciated!

Best regards,
Alexey.

Comment: are you using serializers?

Comment: @arpit-solanki No, I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:**

```
import json
data=[368625, 507694, 687854, 765213, 778491, 1004752, 1024781, 1303354, 1311339, 1407238, 1506842, 1530012, 1797981, 2113318, 2179297, 2312363, 2361973, 2610241, 3005224, 3252169, 3291575, 3333882, 3486264, 3860625, 3964299, 3968863, 4299124, 4907284, 4941503, 5120504, 5210060, 5292840, 5460981, 5622576, 5746708, 5757967, 5968243, 6025451, 6040799, 6267952, 6282564, 6603517, 7271663, 7288106, 7486229, 7600623, 7981711, 8106982, 8460028, 10471602]
print(json.dumps({"users":[{"id":value} for value in data]}))
```

`import json` imports the json package, which is a JSON serialization/deserialization library

`json.dumps(obj)` takes `obj`, a python object, and serializes it to a JSON string

`[{"id":value} for value in data]` is just a list comprehension which creates a list of python dictionaries with `"id"` mapped to each value in the `data` array

**EDIT: Pagination**
I'm not sure if there's some standard on pagination, but a simple model would be:

```
"data": {
    "prevPage": "id",
    "nextPage": "id",
    "data": [
       ...
    ]
}
```

Honestly, implementing that in python wouldn't be that hard:

```
data=[ ... ]
currentPage={"pageID":0,"data":[]}
prevPage={"pageID":-1}

pageSize=5

for value in data:
    currentPage["data"].append({"id":value})
    if len(currentPage)==pageSize:
        currentPage["prevPage"]=prevPage["pageID"]
        prevPage["nextPage"]=currentPage["pageID"]
        # add currentPage to some database of pages
        prevPage=currentPage
        currentPage={"pageID":"generate new page id","data":[]}
```

Obviously, this isn't very polished, but shows the basic concept.

**EDIT: Pagination without storing pages**

You could of course recreate the page every time it is requested:

```
def getPage(pageNum)
    #calculate pageStart and pageEnd based on your own requiremnets
    pageStart = (pageNum // 5) * 5
    pageEnd = (pageNum // 5)*5+5
    return [{"id":data[idx] for idx in range(pageStart, pageEnd)}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! What would you suggest about paginating?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki question was edited after answer was posted, also answer is now updated

Comment: @AlexeyKislitsin Answer has been edited to explain pagination

Comment: Thank you again! what do you mean saying "add currentPage to some database of pages"?

Comment: @AlexeyKislitsin if you are doing pagination, you are going to need to keep each page stored somewhere, so that the server can find it when needed. Another way to do it would be to recalculate the page every time, if performance wasn't a big requirement (also added to answer)