# Django pagination without serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My api return json with data based in key/store etcd , so no queryset

I would like add pagination , but i don't use model and serializer

It's possible to add pagination without this ?

Comment: Can you share an example of your data, that you want to paginate?

Comment: This can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635903/how-to-turn-a-list-into-a-paginated-json-response-for-rest

Comment: Yes, you can paginate `json` but we need see some code, data, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do pagination without querysets, Django already has a [paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/) that allows you to paginate lists of objects, have a look at it's [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/paginator/).

```
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
>>> p = Paginator(objects, 2)
>>> p.count
4
>>> p.num_pages
2
>>> type(p.page_range)
<class 'range_iterator'>
>>> p.page_range
range(1, 3)
>>> page1 = p.page(1)
>>> page1
<Page 1 of 2>
>>> page1.object_list
['john', 'paul']
```

Comment: i don't use queryset , my data it's not based on database model

Comment: @ChristopheFerreira that's exactly what I'm saying, that you can use pagination without a queryset. If you look at the example it paginates a list of strings.